# Run an if statement for each element of a certain class in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

Each `input` in a certain area of a form have the `.validate` class. The problem is, is when an if statement is run, this one in particular:

```
$("#form").live('submit', function(){
if($(".validate").val()=="")
    return false;
else
    return true;
});
```

if only one of them has a single character in them, it will consider them all filled out and let the form submit. Is there a way to run this statement on all `input.validate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
$("#form").live('submit', function(){
  $(".validate").each(function(index,value){
    if($(this).val() == "")
      return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [jquery's $.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to check for all inputs